# Reading JSON to update a table

Tags: python, json

I need a suggestion on writing Python code for updating a table from JSON.

Below is the sample JSON - I need to read the Actual word from JSON and compare with the target table and update the Mapping word in the table.

```
{'World': 'Kairat kajdk Qaeda nurtas download free', 'Hello': 'BK Aziza and Rinat'}

Actual  Word (1) - 'World' Mapping Word (1) - 'Kairat kajdk Qaeda    nurtas download free'

Actual Word (2) - 'Hello'
Mapping Word (2) - 'BK Aziza and Rinat'

Target table

Actual_Word     Mapping Word
Hello
World
World
Hello
World
```

Comment: ur saying updating table . do u mean .u wan tto write sql query

Comment: this may be a good place to start: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: What data structure are you using for your table? Have you written any code yet? Without more information about what you're actually doing, I don't know that you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: I need to write python code to parse the JSON and update the mapping word in the database table. The database table already has the Actual word populated. Now using python I will connect to the database, for each actual word that is present in the JSON, I need to match it to the database table and update the mapping word. The JSON is being generated from the other python code.

Answer (score 0):

Uses **iteritems** feature from dict

```
data = {'World': 'Kairat kajdk Qaeda nurtas download free', 'Hello': 'BK Aziza and Rinat'}

for key, value in data.iteritems():
    print 'Key: %s' % key
    print 'Value: %s' % value

Key: World
Value: Kairat kajdk Qaeda nurtas download free
Key: Hello
Value: BK Aziza and Rinat
```